# PhantomJSDriver change document.referrer

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Is it possible to programmatically change a browser navigation history(or referrer) using PhantomJSDriver without visiting a real website ?

For example, after

```
driver.get("site2.com");
```

I need to have "site1.com" as a referrer of "site2.com".

Also, if this is not possible with PhantomJSDriver could you please recommend some other tool where this  can be possible ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.